# Why does a string equal zero in bash test

Tags: bash, testing

I have an array which I am using to generate a list which a user can choose from made like this.

```
list=(a b c d)
n=0
for x in ${list[@]}
    do echo $n\)$x
    n=$((n++)
done
read -p "Pick an item:" choice
```

I want to allow only valid options to be chosen so I am checking like this.

```
if [[ $choice -gt ${#list[@]} && $choice -lt -1 ]]
    then ...
else
    echo "not a valid choice"
```

The issue I am having is all strings evaluate at equal to zero. ie `[[ "I am a duck" -eq 0 ]]`  is True, as is `(( "I am a duck"  == 0 ))`.  Is there a way to make all string and number comparison evaluate to false?  I know I can check for a string with `[[ $choice =~ [A-Za-z]+ ]]`, but I am wondering if there is a way without regular expressions?

**EDIT**
Sorry, I should have tested the "I am a duck" statement before I put it down.  It doesn't like the spaces.  However, "I_am_a_duck" does evaluate to 0.  This explained by chepner below.

Comment: What's the actual code? What you provide won't run: missing `done`; missing second `)`, etc.

Comment: `[[ "I am a duck" -eq 0 ]]` should be triggering a syntax error, since `I am a duck` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: I get `-bash: [[: I am a duck: syntax error in expression (error token is "am a duck")` (and since there was an error, the comparison fails and it's treated as false).

Comment: Try pasting your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/, which will tell you all sorts of things you can fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-gt`, because it is intended to compare integers, triggers the same behavior for strings as seen in an arithmetic expression: the string is treated as the name of a parameter, and that parameter is expanded (repeat the process if necessary) until you get an integer. If there is no parameter by that name, 0 is substituted.

That said, you could weasel your way out of the problem by number your items starting at one and using

```
if (( choice < 1 || choice > ${#list[@]} )); then
    echo "not a valid choice"
```

since now any non-integer inputs will be treated as 0, which is indeed less than the lower limit of 1.

Comment: Wow.  This explains so much.  So if I say `[[ k -eq 0 ]]` it is actually doing  `[[ $k -eq 0 ]]`, and since it is not defined it evaluates to 0.  Fascinating.  While not the exact answer I was looking for, it does unambiguously answer the name in the title. Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select) for this and not deal with behaviour of strings in arithmetic contexts (as explained in chepner's answer) at all:

```
list=(a b c d)

PS3='Pick an item: '
select opt in "${list[@]}"; do
    case $opt in
        [abcd]) echo "Choice: $opt ($REPLY)" ;;
        *) echo "Illegal choice" ;;
    esac
done
```

This will keep looping; to continue after a valid selection, there has to be a `break` somewhere. The main benefit is `select` taking care of invalid inputs for you, and you don't have to build the menu yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward select.  I initially ignored this because the man page for select is for something totally different.  Thanks for linking to the bash manual.

Comment: @jeffpkamp Yep, it's a built-in, document in `man bash` and `help select`.